# Haskellを使い、リスト内の数字をすべて掛け合わせるコードを書きたい

Tags: haskell

いま、学校の課題でHaskellを使ってタイトルにもあるようにリスト内の数字をすべて掛け合わせるコードを書いています。

例）[1,2,3,4,5] -> 120

現段階での僕のコードは以下のようになっています。

```
myproduct :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
myproduct[] = 0
myproduct(x:xs) = x*(myproduct xs)
```

色々なサイトなどを参照しながら書いてみたんですがどれもうまくいってません。

また、fold functionを使わないといけないのですが、どうすればいいか全くわからない状態まで来てしまいました。
どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。また解説等も載せてくれると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: もしも解決してるのなら [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) を参考に。解決していないのなら質問書き足すとかコメントするとか, どうぞ

Answer (score 3):

0に何をかけても0になので、

```
myproduct[] = 0
```

だと、必ず答えは0になってしまいます。

```
myproduct[] = 1
```

とすれば、うまくいくはずです。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず [Try Haskell](https://tryhaskell.org/) で動いたので

累積和の場合

```hs
foldl (+) 0 [1 .. 10]
-- 55
-- :: (Enum b, Num b) => b
```

累積積の場合

```hs
foldl (*) 1 [1 .. 5]
-- 120
-- :: (Enum b, Num b) => b
```

---

##### 追記

> また、fold functionを使わないといけないのですが

まず, fold使わない場合はこんな感じ

```hs
sum []         = 0
sum (x:xs)     = x + sum xs

product []     = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

fold使うと (最初に書いたように)こんな感じ

```hs
sum     = foldr (+) 0
product = foldr (*) 1
```

`foldl`使うか `foldr`使うかは(内容に合わせて)適当に。
例えば `foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]` なら
`1:(2:(3:[]))` のようになり
`1+(2+(3+0))` のように変換されます